# Extract JSON object values/keys without using hardcoded keys using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, jsonparser

```
 cart = {
 "Items": 3,
 "Item": {
      "Apple iPhone 5S": {
              "productId": 688,
              "url": "http://website.com/phone_iphone5s.html",
              "price": 299.99
        },
      "Solio Mono Solar Charger": {
              "productId": 655,
              "url": "http://website.com/solio_charger.html",
              "price": 29.95
        },
       "24 Month Warranty Package": {
              "productId": 681,
              "url": "http://website.com/24_month_warranty.html",
              "price": 129.95
        }
  },
"Total": 459.89
 }
```

I want to write a **JavaScript** function that outputs the total number of items, each item with price, and the total value of the shopping cart in the browser dev tools console. Eg : **Need to select Apple Iphone 5S and its price, Solio Mono Solar Charger and its price etc**. Without using ***hardcoded keys*** (e.g. “Apple iPhone 5S“, “Solio Mono Solar Charger“). Is there any way ??

Is it possible to get in this format ??

```
   Items: 3 
    - Apple iPhone 5S ($299.99) 
    - Solio Mono Solar Charger ($29.95) 
    - 24 Month Warranty Package ($129.95)
   Total: 459.89
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Siva. Please could you add the code you've attempted to your question, please, as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this

```
var str = `Items: ${cart.Items} `;
Object.keys(cart.Item).forEach((key) => {
  str += `- ${key} (${cart.Item[key].price}) `
})

str +=  `Total: ${cart.Total}`
console.log(str)
```

```js
var cart = {
  "Items": 3,
  "Item": {
    "Apple iPhone 5S": {
      "productId": 688,
      "url": "http://website.com/phone_iphone5s.html",
      "price": 299.99
    },
    "Solio Mono Solar Charger": {
      "productId": 655,
      "url": "http://website.com/solio_charger.html",
      "price": 29.95
    },
    "24 Month Warranty Package": {
      "productId": 681,
      "url": "http://website.com/24_month_warranty.html",
      "price": 129.95
    }
  },
  "Total": 459.89
}


var str = `Items: ${cart.Items} `;
Object.keys(cart.Item).forEach((key) => {
  str += `- ${key} (${cart.Item[key].price}) `
})

str +=  `Total: ${cart.Total}`
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get in this format ?? 

    Items: 3
    - Apple iPhone 5S ($299.99)
    - Solio Mono Solar Charger ($29.95)
    - 24 Month Warranty Package ($129.95)
    Total: 459.89

Comment: But can we use Javascript instead of Jquery ?

Comment: the above code in on pure JS in ES6 standards, not jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them and grab the data wanted like this.

You can edit it to fit whatever you need.

```
cart = {
 "Items": 3,
 "Item": {
      "Apple iPhone 5S": {
              "productId": 688,
              "url": "http://website.com/phone_iphone5s.html",
              "price": 299.99
        },
      "Solio Mono Solar Charger": {
              "productId": 655,
              "url": "http://website.com/solio_charger.html",
              "price": 29.95
        },
       "24 Month Warranty Package": {
              "productId": 681,
              "url": "http://website.com/24_month_warranty.html",
              "price": 129.95
        }
  },
"Total": 459.89
 }

for (var key in cart.Item) {
    if (cart.Item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " " + cart.Item[key]);
    }
}
```